# Best approach to display large amount of text on Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I have a list of store addresses that I want to display (about 100).  The data is being read from a database.

Each address will look like this:
**Main Store**
29 Main Street, City, State
Tel. (123) 456-7890
Fax. (123) 456-7890

The name of the store will be bold and slighter larger font than the rest of the address.

Is my only option to read through the table, and for each record, add a new Textfield or LabelField to a VerticalManager?

Or is there a better approach to handle large amounts of text that still require some formatting?

Looked at RichTextField, but it doesnt have any kind of appendText method, just to setText

Answer (score 1):

For this I would use the ListField, or if you want to have some data normally hidden, then revield by user action use the TreeField.

Comment: Good answer.  I sat down for 2 minutes asking myself, why didnt I choose the listfield.  Then I remembered that not every record have a tel and fax number.  And some records have many telephone numbers.  Since all rows had to be the same height, I found myself sizing to the largest which left some rows having some blank lines.  I didnt like the look.  I want it read as many paragraphs, allowing the user to scroll to the end.

Comment: Then maybe you want a TreeField, though I haven't looked at it in a while so I can't remember if it has similar constraints. The problem with using structured collections of UI objects is the amount of overhead associated with each object. Depending on how modern your target devices are, you could easily run out of resources trying to get all your data displayed. This is why the ListField and TreeField are structured the way they are, they don't use per element UI objects.